# How to override vendor plugin class file in src folder in cakephp4

Tags: class, plugins, overriding, vendor, cakephp-4.x

In my cakephp project I have installed Audit-Stash plugin via composer. It appeared in 'vendor/lorenzo/audit-stash' folder. Here you can find audit stash plugin https://github.com/lorenzo/audit-stash.
Now I want the override some files from audit stash plugin in my project source folder because I want some updations in plugin without changing plugin's original files.
This is in my app.local file where the plugin is loaded.

````
'AuditStash' => [
        'persister' => 'AuditStash\Persister\TablePersister'
    ],
In Application.php
```public function bootstrap(): void
    {
        $this->addPlugin('AuditStash');

Please tell me if there is any solution to this.
````

Comment: If you want to override a template, [here's the documentation for that](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/plugins.html#overriding-plugin-templates-from-inside-your-application). If you want to override some other piece of functionality, you probably have to implement your own class which extends the one you want to override.

Comment: Ok. Thank you!! It's working.

Comment: You can extend this plugin with your own plugin. Bake a new plugin eg. myAuditStash and extend the classes you need to change. Don't forget to load this plugin with `cake plugin load myAuditStash`.